# Join FeatureCollection based on multiple Feature properties using Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, attribute-joins, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-collection

I have 2 timeseries FeatureCollection collected from Landsat looks similar to the following tables.

**1st FeatureCollection (fc1):**

| ID | Date | prop_1 | prop_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **2022/10/01 missing in fc2** | **0.1** | **0.15** |
| 1 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.19 |
| 2 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.3 |

**2nd FeatureCollection (fc2):**

| ID | Date | prop_1 | prop_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| **2** | **2022/10/01 missing in fc1** | **0.25** | **0.37** |
| 2 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.3 |

I want to join them together into a single FeatureCollection based on feature properties named **ID** and **Date**, to keep both matching and non-matching rows.

**Final FeatureCollection:**

| ID | Date | prop_1 | prop_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **2022/10/01** | **0.1** | **0.15** |
| 1 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.19 |
| **2** | **2022/10/01** | **0.25** | **0.37** |
| 2 | 2022/10/02 | 0.2 | 0.3 |

Comment: Not sure why the table format is not showing properly.

Comment: I fixed the tables. It seems there needs to be a blank line before each one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a composite property out of the two, merge the collections and `distinct` on the composite property.

```
function makeKey(f) {
    return f.set('key', f.getString('ID').cat(f.get('date')))
}
c1 = c1.map(makeKey)
c2 = c2.map(makeKey)
var c3 = c1.merge(c2).distinct('key')
```

Comment: Sorry about the downvote. It was a mitake. Actually, I was trying to save for later.